# How to pass multiple values of selected radio button in React JS

Tags: reactjs

how to retrieve radio button selected value and name. I used the selectedOption and it only retrieve the value. Thanks.
App.js

```
const tuitions=[
  {name:"In-state Resident", tuition: 1000, key:1 },
  {name:"Out-state Resident",tuition: 2000, key: 2}
];

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={

    };
  }

  _RadioClickHandler=(event)=>{
    this.setState({
      selectedOption:event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form>
         {tuitions.map(item=>(
           <RadioGroup 
             value={item.value} 
             key={item.key} 
             name={item.name} 
             onChange={this._RadioClickHandler.bind(this)}  
           />)
          )}
          <p>Display 
            <InstitutionList 
              selectedList={this.state.selectedList} 
              resident={this.state.selectedOption}
            />  
          </p>
```

//this.state.selectedOption only pass the value

RadioGroup.js

```
import React from 'react';

const radioGroup=(props)=>{
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        type="radio"
        name="School"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onChange}
      />
      {props.name}
    </div>
  );
}
export default radioGroup;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it to your change handler like so:
`onChange={e => this._RadioClickHandler (e, item.name) }`
Take a look at the snippet below to see it work:

```js
const tuitions = [
  { value: 'ValueA', key: 'KeyA', name: 'Name A' },
  { value: 'ValueB', key: 'KeyB', name: 'Name B' },
  { value: 'ValueC', key: 'KeyC', name: 'Name C' }
];

const RadioButton = (props) => (
    <label>
      <input 
        type="radio"
        name="Schools"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onChange}
      />
      {props.name}
    </label>
  );

class Thingy extends React.Component {
  _RadioClickHandler = (e, name) => {
    alert(`Value:${e.target.value}, Name:${name}`);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {tuitions.map(item=>(
           <RadioButton 
             value={item.value} 
             key={item.key} 
             name={item.name} 
             onChange={e => this._RadioClickHandler (e, item.name) }  
           />
           )
         )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Thingy />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```